# Successful action type not appear on timeline

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I have a simple facebook app, when I click a button with javascript function, I show me `Post was successful! Action ID: 685335521499641`, **but** not appear on the timeline. Also, when I go to `Open Graph` -> `Stories` for check, my meta tags is not functioning right, only the image if I change it. I get the POST code from `Get Code` with some change on it.

I read many comments, but nothing for my issue. So how can I make it right ?

The function is:

```
FB.api('/me/the_name:action_type', 'post', {
           photo: "http://samples.ogp.me/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
           image: "http://path_to_my_image.jpg",
           title: "The sample photo",
           description: "Just for test !!!",  
        },    
        function(response) {
            var msg = 'Error occured';
            if (!response || response.error) {  
                if (response.error) {
                    console.log(response.error);
                    msg += "\n\nType: "+response.error.type+"\n\nMessage:"+response.error.message;
                }
                alert(msg);
            }
            else {
                alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
            }
        }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case may be that, you have not submitted the actions for the approval yet.

But you can check the story in the **Activity log** in your timeline. Or, directly with this url: `https://www.facebook.com/me/activity/RESPONSE_ID`

Once approved, the stories will appear in the news feed.

Comment: Thanks !!! Just asking why my meta tags in the <head> don't work right, only the image, but the image isn't big, that's why I use action type, so it will be bigger than usual.

Comment: You can check in the debugger what exactly facebook sees in your url. Here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: thanks one more time for the help. If I check `http://samples.ogp.me/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` in [developers.facebook.com/tools/debug](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) it show me those wrong meta tags, how can I change them.
If I change my code to: `FB.api('/me/the_name:action_type?image=http://path_to_my_image.jpg&title="The simple photo"&description="Just for test !!!"', 'post', function(response) { ... }` it show me an error: *Error occured Type: Exception Message: The action you're trying to publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects. At least on

Answer (score 0):

If someone have the same issue like mine, think I success, **it's work for me** *for now*.
So first generate new own object with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/object-browser , with correct App: and Object Owner:, mine was `http://samples.ogp.me/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` (from Get Code). In there put only the URL (may be and title), where the meta tags are, it will get the meta tags for this URL.
So it will be 1st version.

```
FB.api('/me/the_name:action_type',  
'post',
{  
photo: "http://The_URL_with meta_tags",  
image: "http://path_to_my_image.jpg",  
title: "The simple photo",  
description: "Just for test !!!",  
},  
function(response) {
 ... see above ...
}  
});
```

2nd version: Allow the User Messages and User Generated Photos if will want big image and comment.

```
FB.api('/me/the_name:action_type?image[0][url]=http://path_to_my_image.jpg&image[0][user_generated]=true',  
'post',
{  
photo: "http://The_URL_with meta_tags",  
message: "a simple message will appear above the image" ,  
},  
function(response) {
 ... see above ...
}  
});
```

I don't know this is the right way, but hope to help if someone have the same issue, it will be for a guide. (if is OK go for submit in Review Status)